# useState hook setter is running only once when called by an EventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, event-listener

In my functional component I'm storing state with useState hook. Every time my user gets to the bottom of the page, I want to add content. So I added an EventListener on 'scroll' inside a useEffect hook.
The thing is it gets triggered the first time I reach the bottom, my new content appears and my page length increase so I can scroll further. But then, nothing append.
With `console.log` I checked if my event was well triggered and it is !

It seems like the callback function given to the event listener is stuck in the past and my setter returns the same state as the first time !

The `gameTeasersToShow` function has 12 elements, I know that if it worked It would crash if I scrolled down a certain good amount of time because the array would not contain enough elems. It's a test.

```
function Index ({ gameTeasersToShow }) {
  console.log(useScrollToBottomDetec())
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([gameTeasersToShow[0], gameTeasersToShow[1], gameTeasersToShow[2]])

  function handleScrollEvent (event) {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= (document.getElementById('__next').offsetHeight)) {
      setState([...state, gameTeasersToShow[state.length]])
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollEvent)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScrollEvent)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {
        state.map(item => {
          const { title, data } = item
          return (
            <GameTeasers key={title} title={title} data={data} />
          )
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` hook looks alright, I have my doubts about the `handleScrollEvent` function though. I think the logic for determining if you've scrolled past the last element is flawed. What is the element with the `__next` id?

Comment: It's my main element, in which I insert all my component. His height is the max height of my page.

Comment: `handleScrollEvent` should be defined inside the `useEffect` that uses it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try that?

```
function handleScrollEvent (event) {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= (document.getElementById('__next').offsetHeight)) {
      setState(oldState => [...oldState, gameTeasersToShow[oldState.length]])
    }
  }
```

Comment: Man thanks a lot, it worked ! What's the difference behaviour between this setter and the usual one ?

Comment: Clearly `state` variable didnt track current value. Probably it is because of asynchronous things underneath. lambda with old state as parameter makes sure you would update state based on the old one.